# Websphere MQ Server configuration to allow incoming connections from client

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I've made a simple websphere client in the past, to connect to our client's websphere mq server - it works.

Now, I want to use it to play around and test my own webspehere mq server (trial edition).
I've downloaded the 8.0.0.4 websphere MQ server for windows, installed it,but now I have issues connecting to it. I've tried a couple of things, manually configuring everything according to some online tutorial but then i tried a simpler approach, uninstalled everything and reinstalled again, and used websphere's default configuration tool.

It went smooth, I could use the postcard application quick and easy.
However, now I'm trying to access it via my own client (c#, using the IBM client libraries).
It appears I can connect to the listener.
By default, there are two channels created in MQ.
S_SomeName and TO_QM_SomeName.
If I connect to S_SomeName, I get error "2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED" - which seems a good indication that everything is working, as that is some server connection, and it uses admin user, which is by default blocked from accessing it as a client. (that's how i understand that. I'm quite new to this).

So I went to try the TO_QM_SomeName hoping it would give me access to any of the queues made by default or made by me.
But now, I get error "2059 MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE" or "2539 MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR" - i've been playing with library versions/server settings, don't remember on which one i got which error. Well...I'm kind of lost now. I cannot find any settings for enabling some user permissions or anything to make it work.
What am I missing? What steps are necessary to make the default configuration work also for clients connecting from localhost/somewhere on the network?

Comment: I suspect that the channel named TO_QM_SomeName is not a server connection channel, and only those can accept connections from MQ clients.

Comment: What do the client and queue manager error logs say? Update the question with that information.

Comment: @Attila Repasi indeed, you are right. I was getting confused which channel does what. In fact, the S_SomeName was the channel I was supposed to connect to.

Comment: @Morag Hughson Thanks for the tip, i couldn't find logs at first, but then found them and solved the issue myself.

Comment: If there is one thing I would wish to teach all new MQ users, it would be to remember to look in the logs. They are full of useful gems! Glad you are sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer thanks to a suggestion in the comments to take a look into logs. (I'm completely new to mq server :)
So, first thing was locating the logs, which were C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\\errors rather than in program files (which the documentation pointed me to at first).
Next, simply reading and analyzing the logs gave me a clue as to what was wrong.
I was accessing the incorrect channel TO_QM_SomeName (as also commented) instead of S_SomeName. However, to access S_SomeName I had to either add user/password combination to the client, or remove user/password validation on the server. I chose the second option.
To do that, I had to enter this:
ALTER AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)

REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
in the runmqsc program, and then in mq explorer remove the blocking rule in channels that blocks all connections. And voila, I can connect to my server now. Thanks for the tips.